# What is the best way to paste code into a Trello card?

Tags: trello, copy-paste

When I try to paste code into Trello I get very weird formatting after saving but it seems it does format code, I just can't get it to work right. Currently I'm just putting links to Gist, but I would prefer to just paste it straight in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer here:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code

using markdown is outdated, its not as easy as just using Gist haha, think I'll keep that route... they should really work on their tools.

Comment: I don't feel that merely because someone feels Tool-A is "not just as easy as" Tool-B that that makes Tool-A "outdated" and worthless.  I happen to love Markdown, and it is used by far more tools than Gist.  Plus, Gist is aimed really at CODE -- Markdown is aimed at DOCUMENTATION.  Two different tools.

Answer (score 35):

Include formatted code by wrapping it in three backticks (```) at the beginning and end of the block, or by starting a line with four spaces.

Important note — **the triple backticks have to be on a separate line and ensure you have a blank line before and after the code block.**

Comment: Adding a tab or 4 spaces at the beginning of each code line (as other users have answered) looks way better. 

I don't understand why this answer has so many upvotes.

Comment: While @LucioMollinedo is correct, it requires "work" :-)  For those of us who are lazy simply pasting text and surround it with ``` is easy.   The BIG point in this answer is the bold section regarding Blank Lines above and below!!  I knew of ``` but couldn't get it work until I found this.

Comment: @ripvlan I agree. Trello needs to improve its formatting tools. 
Doing the same here in StackOverflow is trivial in comparison. 
Still, I go the extra mile and add the tab/4 spaces in my code editor and paste the code in Trello afterwards because readability is very important :-)

Answer (score 7):

Either surround the code by backticks (`` ` ``) for smaller segments of code, or make sure that each line begins with a tab or at least four spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In 2020, wrapping a code block in ``` (triple backticks) in Trello still drops newlines, etc.

I have to add 4 spaces before each line to get it display lines and indentation properly. Thanks @GiH for leading me to the source docs.

https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#precode

Comment: You need a blank line before and after the triple backticks to separate the code block from the rest of the card text.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the subject is a bit old, but I found myself faced with this problem.

I wrote an [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) if anyone is interested in it.
It works with triple backslash with line feed and allows syntax highlighting, according to the indicated language.

(edit: [here](https://gist.github.com/AsyncWizard/c6017edff56c08ab37189939e0e5d012))

Eg:

````
# Title

Text line

```javascript
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import App from './App.vue';

    let vm = new Vue({
        el: '#box',
        render: h => h(App)
    });
```

Text...
````

Result:

[image: Trello syntax highlight result]